# click event not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to handle the click event using jQuery

on upload success, I am creating the following using jQuery:

```
$("#uploadedImage").append( "<div class='img-wrap'>
    <span class='deletePhoto'>&times;</span>
    <img data-id='"+files[i]+"' src='"+asset_url+"uploads/ad_photo/"+files[i]+"'>
  </div>
  <span class='gap'></span>");
```

and for handling click event for the above created div's I have written this:

```
$('.img-wrap .deletePhoto').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

the above code is working properly and creates all div, but when I click on the deletePhoto span. no jQuery alert is showing.

Any help or suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delegate the event and change as suggested:

```
$("#uploadedImage").on('click', '.deletePhoto', function() {
```

---

You have to delegate your event to the closest static parent `#uploadedImage` *in your case* which is available on the page load like the container which holds the newly appended div and image.

although `$(document) and $(document.body)` are always available to delegate the event.

Comment: sir i am using `$(document).on('click', '.img-wrap .deletePhoto', function() {` given by you as your first answer.. then you have updated your answer...

Comment: yes i also mentioned that to delegate to the closest static parent which is in your case is `#uploadedImage` which is very good in terms of performance instead of delegating to the `$(document)`.

Comment: thank you again sir.. i have updated my code as you suggested..and its working very well... thank you so much sir..

Comment: sir.. i want to know how can i hide `.img-wrap` div after click..for the above same condition..as i have multiple divs with same class name..and i only want to hide the div which was clicked by the user..

Comment: with `$(this).closest('yourdivclassname').hide();` you can hide it.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use on() when you create new element after DOM has been loaded.

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-wrap .deletePhoto', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your element dynamically that is why you would need `.live()`
but this method is deprecated in newer version. 
if you want to use jquery 1.10 or above you need to call your actions in this way:

```
$(document).on('click','element',function(){
  `your code goes in here`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$(".img-wrap .deletePhoto").on('click', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First check in debugging mode that you get length when your code is going to bind click event and another thing bind event must written after that element is appended.

And Also check css of your element (height and width) on which you are clicking and yes

```
$(document).on('click','Your Element',function(){
  //your code goes in here
});
```

Will works fine

Answer (score 0):

use [**`delegate`**](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#uploadedImage').on('click','.img-wrap .deletePhoto',function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

see details delegate and `.on` [**here**](http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change a little in your code.

```
$(".deletePhoto").off("click").on("click",function(){
  //Your Code here
});
```